# Call the UI function in controller class in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-5.3

UI Code: in resources\views\DistributorRegistration.php

```
<?php
class DistributorRegitrationForm
{
    public function distributorRegitrationFormHtml(){
        return  '<h1>Hello</h1>';
    }
}
?>
```

In Controler Class.....

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use resources\views\DistributorRegistration;

```
class DistributorRegistration extends Controller
{
    function VestigePOS_GRNHandler(Request $request){
        $id = $request->input('id');
        return view(DistributorRegitrationForm::distributorRegitrationFormHtml()) ;
    }
}
```

When I call this controller in routes

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DistributorRegitrationForm' not found

Answer (score 0):

1. Which file contains the class `DistributorRegitrationForm`? I'm missing an `use App\...\DistributorRegitrationForm;` in the controller, if it's not in the same namespace.
2. Calling `DistributorRegitrationForm::distributorRegitrationFormHtml()` won't work, unless the method becomes a static method (`public static function`).
3. You have some typos in there ;-)